# Copying filtered cells to powerpoint table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Im relatively new to VBA. Im currently trying to run a code that copies filtered visible cells into powerpoint as a table. The dataset is rather huge and will continue to grow. How do I make the code dynamic and format the table that's being pasted into powerpoint?

Im getting an error Run time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes(unknown member) : Integer out of range. 2795 is not in the valid range of 1 to 75"

I would also like the data set to be formatted whereby the first and second column thats copied from the excel sheet gets transposed as the column headers in ppt.

The table looks like this in excel:

| Product Code | Product Name | Keyword | Country | Status | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Kobe Chicken | Chicken | Japan | Imported | NIL |
| 643734 | Hanwook Beef | Beef | Korea | Exported | NIL |

The format i'd like in ppt:

|  | 123456 Kobe Chicken | 643734 Hanwook Beef | (If the products list go on the products would be added via columns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country | Japan | Korea |  | NIL |
| Status | Imported | Exported |  | NIL |
| Description | NIL | NIL |  |

Below is my code:

Also, is there anyway I can get the user to select from the dropdown menu of keyword to set the filtering criterea rather than entering it as a userinput for the code to filter out cells that match the criterea?

```
Sub Export_Range()
    Dim userin As Variant
    Dim userin2 As Variant
    Dim pp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shpTable As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

'To set range
    
   
    userin = InputBox("Please enter the product you'd like to filter by: ")
    userin2 = InputBox("Yes or No?: ")
    
    set rng = Range("B$16:$AG$2810").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$16:$AG$2810").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=userin
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$16:$AG$2810").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=userin2
 
    
'This hides columns that are not needed in copying to ppt

Range("E16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("G16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("H16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("J16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("M16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("O16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("P16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Q16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'Creates new ppt, and adds selected info into table

    pp.Visible = True
    If pp.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        Set ppt = pp.Presentations.Add
    Else
        Set ppt = pp.ActivePresentation
    End If

    Set sld = ppt.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    Set shpTable = sld.Shapes.AddTable(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            shpTable.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                rng.Cells(i, j).Text
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If (rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1) And _
                (rng.Cells(i, j).Text <> "") Then
                shpTable.Table.Cell(i, j).Merge _
                shpTable.Table.Cell(i + rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1, _
                j + rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        rng.Worksheet.Name & " - " & rng.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-vba-to-create-a-table-of-more-than-75/c73995c4-ce00-4c0e-b294-9c3fe3eb1705   Not sure how you would usefully fit a 2795-row table on a slide though...

Comment: @TimWilliams The products shown will be filtered out. There will not be 2000+ rows. It will only be 10-20 rows of products that are based off the filter.

Comment: Instead of `rng.Rows.Count` you probably need something (after the filter is applied) like `rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` tell you how many visible rows you have.  But you want to pivot your data for the PPT table, so that will not be the number of rows for that table: it only has 4 rows including the header row.

Comment: Second half of your code is from https://www.appsloveworld.com/vba/100/7/excel-vba-excel-macro-to-create-table-in-a-powerpoint but doesn't seem that relevant to what you describe as the required end result?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes its related. Because i do want to extract the data from the filtered excel sheet and transfer it onto the powerpoint in a table format. So basically im trying to marge the 2 codes together

Comment: I meant the actual code doesn’t do what you described you wanted.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah it doesnt. Im struggling with the range part- basically its not picking up the range unless i hard code it, but id like to do a dynamic range which is set based on the autofilters

Comment: I can help you but no access to a PC for a few days…

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do this.  I'm not sure if you simplfied your actual use case but I used this table for testing:

[image]

End Result:

[image]

Code:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    'Add project reference to `Microsoft PowerPoint xx.x Object Library`
    Dim loProds As ListObject, rngVis As Range, colKeyWord As ListColumn
    Dim c As Range, rw As Range, visCount As Long, col As Long
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application, ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide, pptable As PowerPoint.Table
    Dim indxProdCode As Long, indxProdName As Long
    Dim indxCountry As Long, indxStatus As Long, indxDescr As Long
    
    'info is in listobject "Products" on worksheet "Listing"
    Set loProds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Listing").ListObjects("Products")
    
    'filter on Keyword = "Beef"
    loProds.ShowAutoFilter = True
    Set colKeyWord = loProds.ListColumns("Keyword")
    loProds.Range.AutoFilter Field:=colKeyWord.Index, Criteria1:="Beef"
                             
    'get visible cells in keyword column
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no visible cells
    Set rngVis = colKeyWord.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then 'no rows left after filtering?
        MsgBox "No rows visible after applying filter...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    visCount = rngVis.Cells.Count 'how many visible rows left?
    
    'start PPT, add a new presentation, and put a table on slide 1
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppApp.Visible = True
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add()
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    Set pptable = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTable(4, visCount + 1).Table
    
    SetText pptable.cell(2, 1), "Country"      'fixed row headers in column 1
    SetText pptable.cell(3, 1), "Status"
    SetText pptable.cell(4, 1), "Description"
    
    'find the column indexes of the content we want to extract from `loProds`
    indxProdCode = loProds.ListColumns("Product Code").Index
    indxProdName = loProds.ListColumns("Product Name").Index
    indxCountry = loProds.ListColumns("Country").Index
    indxStatus = loProds.ListColumns("Status").Index
    indxDescr = loProds.ListColumns("Description").Index
    
    col = 1
    'loop over each visible row and populate a new column in the table
    For Each c In rngVis.Cells
        Set rw = Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, loProds.DataBodyRange) 'the table row for this cell
        col = col + 1 'next ppt table column
        SetText pptable.cell(1, col), rw.Cells(indxProdCode).Value & " " & rw.Cells(indxProdName).Value
        SetText pptable.cell(2, col), rw.Cells(indxCountry).Value
        SetText pptable.cell(3, col), rw.Cells(indxStatus).Value
        SetText pptable.cell(4, col), rw.Cells(indxDescr).Value
    Next c
    
End Sub

'helper method for setting table cell text
Sub SetText(cell As PowerPoint.cell, v)
    cell.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = v
End Sub
```